# Identify many gameobjects when clicked in screen and interact with the selected gameobject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 5 objects in a map and when I tap in the screen on any of them a text message appears. How can I do it more easily when I'll have a lot of objects (over 500)? What's the best way to do it?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SeleccionarTesoro : MonoBehaviour {


public GameObject infotesoro0001A;
public GameObject infotesoro0002A;
public GameObject infotesoro0003A;
public GameObject infotesoro0004A;
public GameObject infotesoro0005A;

void Update() {

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) 
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
        if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit)) 
        {
            if (hit.collider.gameObject.name == "tesoro_0001") {
                infotesoro0001A.SetActive (true);
            }
            if (hit.collider.gameObject.name == "tesoro_0002") {
                infotesoro0002A.SetActive (true);
            }
            if (hit.collider.gameObject.name == "tesoro_0003") {
                infotesoro0003A.SetActive (true);
            }
            if (hit.collider.gameObject.name == "tesoro_0004") {
                infotesoro0004A.SetActive (true);
            }
            if (hit.collider.gameObject.name == "tesoro_0005") {
                infotesoro0005A.SetActive (true);
            }
        }
    }
}   
}
```

UPDATED: making with a list

Original question: [I have 5 objects in a map and when I tap in the screen on any of them a text message appears. How can I do it more easily when I'll have a lot of objects (over 500)? What's the best way to do it?]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SeleccionarTesoro_LIST : MonoBehaviour {


public List<GameObject> hitObject;


public void SetHitObjectToActive(GameObject hitObject)
{
    hitObject.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject.SetActive (true);
    hitObject.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(2).gameObject.SetActive (true);

}

void Update() {

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) 
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);


            if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit)) {
                SetHitObjectToActive (hit.collider.gameObject);
            }

        }
}
}
```

Comment: You really need to use collections, rather than distinct variables.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts I've updated the question trying to solve it with a List, but doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered creating a method that takes the hit gameobject as an argument?

```
public void SetHitObjectToActive(GameObject hitObject)
{
    hitObject.SetActive(true);
}
```

Then you can call the method like so

```
if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit)) 
{
    SetHitObjectToActive(hit.collider.gameObject);   
}
```

Also, you'll likely want to store all those objects in a collection.

```
public List<GameObject> yourObjects;
```

Comment: I was thinking of doing with a list bit don't know how identify each object i tap in the screen. Can you help me?

Comment: Updated to make my answer clearer. You don't need to identify the objects this way because the hit object is already referenced.

Comment: I've updated my code trying to resolve with list but doesn't work for me. Could you check the code I've added? Thanks

Comment: You don't need to loop through your objects because the object you hit is referenced in hit.collider.gameObject. I recommend reviewing how object instances work: http://www.introprogramming.info/english-intro-csharp-book/read-online/chapter-11-creating-and-using-objects/

Comment: You're welcome. In any stack exchange forum, if your question is answered, mark the reply as correct :)